# C# basic Dictionary Ordering Just need to clear an error

Tags: c#, dictionary, sorting

I adjusted this more and came up with the following code and I think my only problem is how I instruct it to read from textbox1 and output into textbox2 with the sorting instructions.  I've been fighting this for days off and on if someone could help me out, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        myDict.Add("one", 1);
        myDict.Add("four", 4);
        myDict.Add("two", 2);
        myDict.Add("three", 3);

        var sortedDict = (from entry in myDict orderby entry.Value ascending select entry);

        string[] items = textBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
        Array.Sort(items, new ??? ());  
        textBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);




    }

}
}
```

Comment: Could you give the exact error message?

Comment: sure, thx:
Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Comparer' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<string>.Compare(string, string)' C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\Form1.cs 19 22 WindowsFormsApplication4

Comment: What is your "Comparer" supposed to be doing? At the moment it ... creates a new dictionary and puts some stuff in it? I should either remove the `: IComparer<string>` part from the class declaration, or actually make it a comparer rather than a ... nothing.

Comment: I think that is where I have it wrong.  I'd like to remove that somehow and just allow myself to set the order in which my dictionary sorts.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what order you put things in your dictionary as they will be reordered by the framework.  Your Comparer should have a Compare method that looks a little like this

```
public int Compare(string x, string y)
{
    return _dict[x].Compare(_dict[y]);
}
```

[Edit] Just saw the last (scroll-down) bit of your code. This should now look like

```
string[] items = textBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
Array.Sort(items, new Comparer());
textBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Lines = textBox1.Lines.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    }
```

or with custom sorting

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Lines = textBox1.Lines.OrderBy(x => x,new Comparer()).ToArray();
    }
    public class Comparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            //logic here
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the IComparer interface, you have to add a definition for the **Compare** method, and that is what the error message you have seen said.

See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the whole problem could be worked around by simply using the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class instead of a normal dictionary.

Comment: I"m using one, two, three as examples but it will be more involved later.

Comment: Yeah so? Why is that going to stop you using a sorted dictionary?

Comment: Oh ok forgive me, I'm still new and have gotten ahead of myself and I just want to wrap up this one task I am helping someone with.  Could you show me how that can work with textboxes and my example?

Comment: He's not asking to sort the Dictionary, he's asking to sort an array of strings based on values by matching the keys in a Dictionary.